# How to create a layer of numbers around an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Say I have an array `B`:

```
B = [1];
```

I want to use a loop to create a layer of zeros around this array, creating a 2D array with the original 1 in the centre.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array and want to create a layer of zeros around it you can use `blkdiag`:

```
A = zeros(padsize);
result = blkdiag(A,B,A);
```

If `B` is just a scalar and you want create a layer of padvals around it you can use `repmat` and indexing.

```
result = repmat(padavl,2*padsize+1);
result(padsize+1,padsize+1) = B;
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have the image processing toolbox, use [`padarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html):

```
B=1;
padvalue = 0; % Value to pad
padsize = 1; % Amount of rows/columns to pad
padarray(B,[padsize  padsize ],padvalue ,'both')
ans =
     0     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     0
```

If you don't have the image processing toolbox, it's easily done by hand:

```
[X,Y] = size(B); % Get sizes
padvalue = 0;
padsize = 1; % Amount of rows/columns to pad
A = padvalue*ones(X+2*padsize ,Y+2*padsize ); % Initialise with a size of 2 larger
A(2:end-1,2:end-1) = B % Fill with original B

A =

     0     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     0
```

Using a loop is actually much more difficult in this case, but you could do it:

```
B = 1;
[X,Y] = size(B); % Get sizes
padvalue = 0;
A = padvalue*ones(X+2*padsize ,Y+2*padsize ); % Initialise with a size of 2 larger
for ii = 1:X
    for jj = 1:Y
        A(ii+padsize ,jj+padsize ) = B(ii,jj); % Grab correct element
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate a few `ones` arrays around the original matrix, I'll use the same `padvalue` and `padsize` syntax as [Adriaan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865232/3978545) for easy comparison:

```
padvalue = 0; % Value to pad around the outside
padsize = 1;  % Depth of padding

B = 1;        % Some matrix
[r,c] = size(B);
A = [ padvalue*ones(padsize,c+2*padsize); 
      [padvalue*ones(r,padsize), B, padvalue*ones(r,padsize)];
      padvalue*ones(padsize,c+2*padsize) ];
```